# ReactQuill: Validating Empty Input Value (Showing html tags)

Tags: reactjs

I have problem regarding validating the ReactQuill.

The Scenario: When i remove the input in ReactQuill Textarea the last value will be

```
<p><br></p>
```

**Question:** How to validate if the last value would be `<p><br></p>` i tried to get value and validate it. but still the value is inserting without data. I don't know where's the problem in my code or in the ReactQuill

[image: Sample Image]

**State:**

```
 const datas = {
    textValue: this.state.text
 }
```

**My Condition:**

```
 if(datas.textValue.length === 0 || datas.textValue.value == '<p><br></p>')
 {
    return 'false';
 }
 else
 {
    return 'true';
 }
```

Comment: Use datas.textValue.length === 1 condition

Answer (score 19):

React Quill uses HTML tags for markup purpose. To check length of the entered text by user, we can just filter out html tags from `datas.textValue` using following regex and trim whitespaces if present.

```
if(datas.textValue.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '').trim().length === 0) {
    //textarea is still empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to add just a bit to @Scorpionsk answer for it to work perfectly for me so it wouldn't escape images as well.

This works for me.

```
function isQuillEmpty(value: string) {
  if (value.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '').trim().length === 0 && !value.includes("<img")) {
     return true;
   }
     return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the extra lines  You can use the following regex

```
const htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/<p>\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*<\/p>/g, '');
```